# Deleteing a record that is in an html table using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm having a little bit of an issue figuring this one out. What I've done is i've created a table using a while loop that displays all my courses into an html table :

```
<?php
include_once "Includes/config.php";

function manCourse(){
    $SQL = "SELECT cname FROM course";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        echo "There are no courses.";
    }
    else 
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {                   
            echo "<tr><td> Course name: <b> " .$row['cname']."</b></td> <td><a href = ''>Edit</a></td> <td><a href = ''>Delete</a></td> </tr>";
        }


    }

}
?>
```

My issue is when someone clicks the delete or edit link it needs to do just that. What can I use as a key so it knows which row it needs to edit or delete?

Any help would be appreciated! thanks.

Comment: How your SQL looks like? Any `id` column? +change `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`.

Comment: _"What can I use as a key"_: How about `course`'s primary key?

Comment: Add primary key of the row in the href as a parameter and get it from url where you write the code for delete

Comment: There is an ID column, yes. My table has around 5 or 6 records at the moment. I understand I can use the primary key, but how exactly would a delete statement know which line to delete? There are as many delete links as there are records.

Comment: You must try to find and learn something more..

Comment: Put the key in your href so its passed back to the server, if that is why you have an href. Otherwise, add the course_id as the id of your TD and attach a javascript function to post the delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 include_once "Includes/config.php";

  function manCourse(){
   $SQL = "SELECT id,cname FROM course";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
   if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
     echo "There are no courses.";
   }
  else 
  {
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {                   
         echo "<tr><td> Course name: <b> " .$row['cname']."</b></td> <td><a href = ''>Edit</a></td> <td><a href = 'delete.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Delete</a></td> </tr>";
     }


  }

}
 ?>
```

delete.php is your new file where you will add code for deleting record. `$row['id']` is primary of record, which is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

Its very good database design to always include a unique primary key for each row. This will solve your issue here, and will allow for other benefits like joining to other tables. This key should then be included in your table, but not visible to the user.

```
create table course 
(
   course_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
   . . .
)
```

Pass that key back from the UI when they click delete, and use this SQL to delete it from the database:

```
delete from course where course_id = $course_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you must create a page named delete.php

the delete.php must have this code.

and you must pass the variable via tha delete link which will be like this

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo " Course name:  **" .$row['cname']."** Edit     Delete ";
  }